# Acessing the name attribute of a <ui:insert>

Tags: jsf, facelets

I have a JSF template with the a title and a subtitle :

```
<h3><ui:insert name="title"/></h3>
<hr/>
<h5><ui:insert name="subtitle"/></h5>
```

All the pages using this template have title, but not always a subtitle :

```
<ui:define name="title">My Title with no subtitle</ui:define>
```

When there is no subtitle I don't want to have a `<hr/>` tag. So what I really want to do is check if `subtitle` is empty, if yes, ignore the block of code. Something like that :

```
<h3><ui:insert name="title"/></h3>
<c:if test="#{not empty subtitle}">
    <hr/>
    <h5><ui:insert name="subtitle"/></h5>
<c:if>
```

But of course `<c:if test="#{not empty subtitle}">` doesn't work. I don't know how to access the value of the `subtitle` variable.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Closest what you can get is to define the subtitle as an `<ui:param>` instead.

Thus,

```
<ui:define name="title">My Title with a subtitle</ui:define>
<ui:param name="subtitle" value="A subtitle" />
```

with

```
<h3><ui:insert name="title"/></h3>
<ui:fragment rendered="#{not empty subtitle}">
    <hr/>
    <h5>#{subtitle}</h5>
</ui:fragment>
```