# How can i check if JSF content was defined?

Tags: templates, jsf, jakarta-ee, facelets

I have this template:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <ui:insert name="content">Content</ui:insert> 
    </td>
    <td class="rightpanel">
        <ui:insert name="rightpanel">RP</ui:insert> 
    </td>
</tr>
```

And i want to render rightpanel cell only if rightpanel content was defined by template client.

Comment: Just Keep it blank. If some thing is defined in template client then it will replace it otherwise it will be blank(or blank page).

Comment: But i don't want render whole `<td>` if ui's content is blank.

Comment: If you want the <td> to be dynamic, don't put it in template. Define it it in template client.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but if someone gets here, look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/5650606/3136474  
I found a better solution there, as the @neni answer looks to me like a workaround.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

Template:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<h:head>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <ui:insert name="content">Content</ui:insert>
        </td>

            <ui:insert name="rightpanel"></ui:insert>

    </tr>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Template Client

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="./TestTemplate.xhtml">

        <ui:define name="content">
               ABCDEF
            </ui:define>
        <ui:define name="rightpanel">
            <h:outputText escape="false" value="<td> ABCD </td>">
            </h:outputText>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
</html>
```

I just used escape characters to render the data. Give a try :)