# How can I wrap optional facelet template content in a div tag?

Tags: templates, jsf-2, facelets

I'm a long time JSP user but facelets newbie and am stuck on what I thought would be a really simple task.

How can I wrap optional template content in a div tag?

For example given the following simplified template:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<html xml:lang="en" lang="en"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

    <h:head>
        <!-- head stuff here -->
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <!-- main body stuff here -->
        <div class="border-box">
            <ui:insert name="optional" />
        </div>
    </h:body>

</html>
```

If I use this template without defining the optional content I'll get an unwanted empty box.

I've searched for a solution and found the same question posed a few times but no real answer.

Can anyone help me out? This seems to me to be quite a reasonable thing to want to do with a templating system but it's got me stumped.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks mael, ui:fragment seems to be the way to go when the content will fit in a ui:param value attribute but I'm going with your first suggestion. I will template-ize the wrapper though with a ui:decorate.

Page template:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xml:lang="en" lang="en"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

    <h:head>
        <!-- head stuff here -->
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <!-- main body stuff here -->
        <ui:insert name="optional" />
    </h:body>

</html>
```

Wrapper template:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<ui:composition
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

    <div class="border-box">
        <ui:insert />
    </div>

</ui:composition>
```

Invocation:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<ui:composition
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    template="page.xhtml">

    <!-- other ui:defines -->

    <ui:define name="optional">
        <ui:decorate template="wrapper.xhtml">
            <!-- optional content -->
        </ui:decorate>
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the `div` and make something like this in the page that uses your template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head />
<body>
<ui:composition template="template.xhtml">
  <ui:define name="optional">
    <div class="border-box">
        <!-- Content here -->
    </div>
</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This rather undermines the purpose of templating doesn't it? The common div tag has to appear every time the template is invoked with all the attendant problems of duplicate code.

Comment: Then you may not need templating but a ui:fragment with a param. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650606/acessing-the-name-attribute-of-a-uiinsert) may be what you need